# How to run shell command xargs with pipe in Python 2.6

Tags: python, shell, pipe

What I really want to run is a shell command with xargs and pipe like following in Python 2.6,

```
grep -lsr "somestring" ./somedir | xargs rm
```

I want to remove all files in `./somedir` with content matching `somestring`.

I tried code as following, but it was not working. Thanks for any inputs.

```
  import subprocess

  p1 = subprocess.Popen('grep -lsr "somestring" ./somedir', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  p2 = subprocess.Popen('xargs rm', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  p1.stdout.close()
  output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Error I'm getting:

```
rm: missing operand
Try `rm --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using shell=True, the first argument to Popen should just be a string not a list.

You could also just run

```
subprocess.check_call("grep -lsr "somestring" ./somedir | xargs rm", shell=True)
```

Comment: Fixed the typo. Edited the post. Tried your solution. Still getting error "rm: missing operand". By the way, I'm using Python 2.6, which I couldn't change personally.

Comment: Did you run just the grep part and make sure it's printing the files you expect to see?

Comment: Just tried to run subprocess.check_call('grep -lsr "somestring" ./somedir', shell=True). Got error: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'grep -lsr "somestring" ./somedir' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: Right.. a non-zero exit means that grep didn't find any matches.. Are you sure you don't mean to be doing ```ls ./somedir | grep "something" | xargs rm```

Comment: Yes. What I want to do is to grep all files in `./somedir` with `somestring` in their content, not in their file names, then delete those files.

Comment: Well grep is returning non-zero because there are no files that match that content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90083/discussion-between-kevinlu-and-chad-simmons).